# Creating weighted geom_histogram()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have an example dataframe:

```
set.seed(100)
my_data <- data.frame(type = letters, 
                      value = rnorm(26, 10, 3) |> sort(),
                      weight = 1:26)
```

I can easily make a histogram:

```
bin_width <- 5
x_seq <- seq(0, 20, bin_width)

ggplot2::ggplot(my_data, ggplot2::aes(x = value)) +
  ggplot2::geom_histogram(binwidth = bin_width) + 
  ggplot2::scale_x_continuous(limits = c(min(x_seq), max(x_seq)),
                                         n.breaks = length(x_seq))
```

[image]

Now, I would like to make a second figure that uses `my_data$weight` as a weighting factor. The resulting figure must match the first - it must have the same x-axis and look like it is a histogram. It does not actually need to be a histogram, but it must match. Instead of showing the number of observations within the bin range, this figure will show the cumulative weighting value of observations within the bin range. In other words, for all observations with `my_data$value` within the bin range, it will sum the `my_data$weight` and display the summed total on the y-axis.

One easy solution is to replicate the data using the weight. For example, `rep(my_data$value, my_data$weight`. This solution does not work for me because in my real dataset the weights are very large and replication as well as plotting is very slow. I am using that solution to show the desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to map your weights on the `weight` aesthetic:

```r
ggplot2::ggplot(my_data, ggplot2::aes(x = value)) +
  ggplot2::geom_histogram(ggplot2::aes(weight = weight), binwidth = bin_width) +
  ggplot2::scale_x_continuous(
    limits = c(min(x_seq), max(x_seq)),
    n.breaks = length(x_seq)
  )
#> Warning: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (`geom_bar()`).
```

[image]